Released Android App Crashes after API Call
I run my MAUI application with release mode. App get started but when it trying to call API app crashes (In my case user login process).I can assure API request fails because I check it form Event Viewer(I set up API application on IIS). My app work well in Debug mode. I disable AOT and app shrinking but it not worked. I have doubt of created HTTP Client for the release mode. Otherwise I couldn't see any fault but there is a fault.
This is how I created the HttpClient:
#if DEBUG
            HttpsClientHandlerService handler = new HttpsClientHandlerService();

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler.GetPlatformMessageHandler());
       
#else
        
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
#endif

How to solve this problem.Any help is highly appreciated.

do you have any exception handling logic?  Or any crash reporting tools?

@Jason The app automatically stopped after clicking the "Login" button in my application. So I think it's from API call.

That's not what I asked.  If you "think" its the API call, then wrap that call in some exception handling to catch the underlying exception

@Jason I added an exception as you mentioned. It says "Connection Failure". But In debug mode, there weren't an issue.

does you app have internet permissions?  I believe that they are added automatically in Android Debug, but not in Release

@Jason I've already setup internet permissions in the "AndroidManifest.xml" file.

Is your permissions same as this

I found the issue. It happened due to a SSL certificate problem.  and Thank you for your help.

Glad to know you have resolved the issue, and you can put the specific steps into an answer.

First, we should create a new folder named "xml" under Android->Platforms->Resources. In the XML folder, we should create a new XML file "network_security_config" to add domains of the API.
This is the interior of that file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <!--<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />-->
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">apps.example.com</domain>
        
        
    </domain-config>
    
</network-security-config>

This is the code line for adding the domain
<domain includeSubdomains="true">apps.example.com</domain>

Additional information:
If you perform USB debugging then add your IP as the domain. In this case, your mobile and PC should be on the same network.
